# Overcome themes's properties set on my List Flex4

Tags: css, list, apache-flex, flex4

I have the following list:

```
<s:List id="list" x="4" y="4" width="99%" height="99%"                      
                        dataProvider="{recordingsShown}"
                        itemRenderer="components.VideoItemRenderer"
                        useVirtualLayout="false"
                        click="launchPopUp(event)">
```

how can i make my list background transparent?because i have applied a theme that defines a white background..i have put the alpha properties in it but nothing.. is there something like !important in css? 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved that by getting the code of the theme for the specific component, created a new custom skin for that with the same code and change the specific attributes i wanted.